# How to return specific cell list into new table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of chocolates with there raw materials grams and i would like to reflect that in another sheet as choosing the chocolate name from a drop down list and automatically list each raw material with grams.

so, below is an example for the sheet as i can't upload pictures yet.
[Example Cost](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g3ktyni70mvuq6/Example%20Costing.xlsx?dl=0)

I want to choose the chocolate and directly see my raw material list with grams in the last table.

can you help me please?

Comment: what have you tried so far? you maybe want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into  Vlookup excel formula. This [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/) can be useful

Use the cell reference where you placed your dropdown as 'reference' and your table with all contents as 'range', your list on your dropdown should be same as columns 1 on your table.